# Cómo puedo pasar un parámetro a un ListView de Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estoy con un blog de noticias. Cuando muestro un post por pantalla, muestro todos sus datos: categoría, titulo, bajada, autor, fecha de creación, contenido y tags. Ahora lo que quiero hacer es al momento de hacer clic en la categoría, ir a buscar todos los posts que se crearon con esa categoría. Para ese caso, tengo en el template detail_post.html el siguiente acceso al link de categorías:

```
<a href={% url 'category' post.category.id %}>{{ post.category }}</a>
```

Mientras tanto tengo en mis urls.py lo siguiente:

```
path('category/<pk>', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category')
```

y mi CategoryListView lo tengo definido asi:

```
class CategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'core/category.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        print(self.request)
        category_id = self.request.GET.get('post.category.id')
        print(category_id)
        if category_id:
            return get_object_or_404(Category, id=category_id)
```

lo que estoy notando es que el print(self.request) me esta devolviendo por consola

```
<WSGIRequest: GET '/category/4'>
```

osea que algo me está trayendo. Me falta rescatar ese "4" en este caso, para filtrar los posts con esa categoría.
Alguien podrá darme una mano con esto ?
Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

pude tener algunos avances. Redefiní la vista de la siguiente forma:

```
class CategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'core/category.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        category_id = self.request.GET['cat']

        if category_id:
            return Post.objects.filter(category = category_id, published=True)

        return super().get_queryset()
```

Tuve que redefinir la url

```
path('category/', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category'),
```

Y los enlaces los tuve que rearmar de la siguiente forma:

```
<a href={% url 'category' %}?cat={{ post.category.id }}>{{ post.category }}</a>
```

Funciona, pero me encontré un detalle. En el template, coloco un alert donde muestro una leyenda, donde pongo algo asi "Estos son todos los posts de la categoría XXXXXX". Bueno, no puedo levantar el nombre de la categoría. Muestro una imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra cosa que no me gusta como queda es que la url queda formada con la estructura:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/?cat=4
```

Pero bueno. Vamos a ver como puedo resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

Listo, pude recuperar el nombre de la categoría y pasarla a través del context

```
class CategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'core/category.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        category_id = self.request.GET['cat']
        if category_id:
            return Post.objects.filter(category = category_id, published=True)

        return super().get_queryset()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category'] = Category.objects.get(id = self.request.GET['cat'])
        return context
```